# Creating a dropdown that dynamically creates another dropdown in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, eloquent

I'm fairly new to Laravel (and I love it!) I'm trying to do something a bit complicated: Creating a drop-down menu that upon selection of an option -will display a second drop-down menu that will give further options dynamically based on the previous selection.

My controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Manufacturer;
use App\GearCategory;
use App\SubCategory;
use App\GearItem;

class GearItemController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth'); 
    }

    public function create(Manufacturer $manufacturers, GearItem $gearItem, GearCategory $gearCategory, SubCategory $subCategory)
    {
        // dd($gearCategory->all());
        $catNum = 6; // <-- needs to be equal to the dispaly div name. Hard coded as 6 for test purposes. 
        $gearCategory = $gearCategory->all();
        $subCategory = $subCategory::where('gear_categories_id', $catNum)->get();
        $manufacturers = $manufacturers->all();


        return view('gearitem.create', compact('gearCategory'), compact('subCategory'), compact('manufacturers'),  compact('gearItem'));
    }
}
```

My blade looks like this:

```
  <div class="card-header">
                    <h3>Add a new gear Item</h3>

                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <select name="gear_categories_id" id="gear_categories_id" class="custom-select mb-3 mt-3"
                        onchange="selector('display_div', this)">
                        <option value="" selected>Choose category</option>
                        @foreach ($gearCategory as $category)
                        <option id="cat_selector" value="{{ $category->id  }}"
                            {{ (old("gear_categories_id") == $category->id ? "selected" : "") }}>{{ $category->name }}
                        </option>

                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>


                <script>
                    "use strict"
                    function selector(divId, element) {

                        console.log(element.value);

                        document.getElementById(divId).setAttribute("name", element.value)

                    }
                </script>



                    <div class="display_div container" id="display_div" name="">

                    <select name="sub_categories_id" id="sub_categories_id" class="custom-select mb-3 mt-3"
                    onchange="selector('display_div', this)">
                    <option value="" selected>Choose item's type</option>
                    @foreach ($subCategory as $scategory)
                    <option id="cat_selector" value="{{ $scategory->id }}"
                        {{ (old("sub_categories_id") == $scategory->id ? "selected" : "") }}>{{ $scategory->name }}
                    </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>

                </div>
```

(Sorry for using vanilla JS i haven't gotten into Vue yet...) I'm trying to pass the name of the "display_div" onto the $catNum variable in the controller (set to "6" just to test if it works but should be set to whatever the user is choosing on the first dropdown) The values of the 'gear_categories_id' appear as a foreign key in the SubCategory model and if i'll manage to feed these values to the second dropdown it would work. I've been struggling for hours with it and I can't figure it out... Please help and sorry for being such a n00b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `AJAX` request on change of the parent category drop-down to populate the subcategories. See the code below. I have added a second route to get `subCategories` for a specific `categoryID`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Manufacturer;
use App\GearCategory;
use App\SubCategory;
use App\GearItem;

class GearItemController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth'); 
    }

    public function create(Manufacturer $manufacturers, GearItem $gearItem, GearCategory $gearCategory, SubCategory $subCategory)
    {
        // dd($gearCategory->all());
        $catNum = 6; // <-- needs to be equal to the dispaly div name. Hard coded as 6 for test purposes. 
        $gearCategory = $gearCategory->all();
        $subCategory = $subCategory::where('gear_categories_id', $catNum)->get();
        $manufacturers = $manufacturers->all();


        return view('gearitem.create', compact('gearCategory'), compact('subCategory'), compact('manufacturers'),  compact('gearItem'));
    }

    public function getSubCategories($categoryID) {
        return  SubCategory::where('gear_categories_id', $categoryID)->get();
    }
}
```

```
Route::get('/sub-categories/{categoryID}', 'GearItemController@getSubCategories');
```

```
<div class="card-header">
    <h3>Add a new gear Item</h3>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <select name="gear_categories_id" id="gear_categories_id" class="custom-select mb-3 mt-3"
        onchange="selector('display_div', this)">
        <option value="" selected>Choose category</option>
        @foreach ($gearCategory as $category)
        <option id="cat_selector" value="{{ $category->id  }}"
            {{ (old("gear_categories_id") == $category->id ? "selected" : "") }}>{{ $category->name }}
        </option>

        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>


    <script>
        "use strict"
        function selector(divId, element) {

            console.log(element.value);

            document.getElementById(divId).setAttribute("name", element.value);


            fetch('/sub-categories/')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(subCategories => {
                var options = subCategories.reduce( (opts, cat) => 
                    `${opts}<option value="${cat.id}">${cat.name}</option>`, "");
                document.getElementById("sub_categories_id").innerHTML = `<option value="" selected>Choose item's type</option>${options}`;
            });

        }
    </script>



<div class="display_div container" id="display_div" name="">

    <select name="sub_categories_id" id="sub_categories_id" class="custom-select mb-3 mt-3"
        onchange="selector('display_div', this)">
        <option value="" selected>Choose item's type</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But is this the only way to pass data from the blade back to the controller? It looks a bit like an overkill, I thought there must be some elegant way to pass the user selection back to the controller without using ajax. I'm surprised such a way doesn't exist as a native feature of Laravel...

Comment: Not really, I mean if you don't want to refresh the page, you are going to have to make an AJAX request

Comment: Or If there is not too much categories and Subcategories, you can just fetch all the subcategories and then filter on the client side. How many `Subcategories` are there?

Comment: For now there are "only" 56 but when the site will be on production I think there might be over a hundred. That is why I'm looking into "cutting" the sub categories dynamically by the first dropdown. So further if i'd like to dynamically display a form based on the choices of the user from the 2 dropdowns I'll probably have to use another AJAX request with yet another route?

Comment: Yes. Basically whenever you need a Separate set of data from the server, in the background, you will have to make a separate request for that. Thus, you will need another route

Comment: Although even 100 is not that large a number. You could fetch all and store them on the client side and then Filter that array based on the array stored in client side. If you really want to avoid creating the extra route

Comment: Would using Vue instead of vanilla Javascript provide a better or more "elegant" solution?

Comment: A JS framework would only help you in client side. So the AJAX request could be made more elegant. You don't even need to actually use a framework. You can just use a library like `axios` or even simple `fetch`

Comment: If you want, I can edit the answer to use the `fetch` library

Comment: That could be interesting! Thanks! Learned a lot from you already...

Comment: I've edited my answer using `fetch`. Read more about `fetch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API